# Tenho dois cadastros agrupados mas só um é alterado no update

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Montei um update agrupando o campo `presenca` que deveria alterar de dois `arrays` em um laço de repetição, segue a `query`:

```
UPDATE acessos AS a
  JOIN
    ( SELECT usr_id, presenca
      FROM acessos
      GROUP BY presenca
    ) AS c
    ON  a.usr_id = c.usr_id

SET 
    a.presenca = 1
    WHERE a.usr_id = 2
```

Ele só funciona com o `usr_id = 10`, o que pode ser?

Comment: Cheguei no safe_update, com o erro 1175 que o workbench me printou.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi com:

```html
@mysql_query("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;", $conn1);
```